# How to convert a formData object to binary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

```js
let file = document.body.files[0],


function convertToBinary(file){
  // code
}
```

There is an API that I will be using to upload a file, and it only takes the file as binary.

I can get it as formData but i have no idea how to parse it into binary.

Comment: I don't see what's so unclear about your question. Quite simple. Don't let it put you off from asking more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use the `FileReader` API

Personally I prefer the ES7 approach far more. But the syntax has taken me a while to get used to.

The advantage to reading the file first is that you can manipulate the binary in the client side before posting if you wanted to.

#### Using ES5

```
function getBinaryFromFile(file, cb) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", cb.bind(this, reader.result));
    reader.addEventListener("error", console.error.bind(this, err));

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

// Usage 
var file = document.body.files[0];

getBinaryFromFile(file, function(binary) {/*API call*/});
```

#### Using ES7 Async/Await

```
// Get binary without ugly callbacks using ES7
function getBinaryFromFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(reader.result));
        reader.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    });
}

// Usage 
var file = document.body.files[0],
    binary = await getBinaryFromFile(file);

// API call
```